# How to get Channel ID (YouTube API v2)?

Tags: get, youtube-api, channel

If i know author or Channel ID then link is worked but i need get my channel ID.

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=[Channel ID]&orderby=viewCount
```

But i don't have a channel ID.
I want using my Google account (My username and password) and get my channel ID using v2 Google Gdata Youtube API, not v3

Thanks for help.

Astin Runa

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the channels endpoint passing the part as id, forUsername and key https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=YOUR_USERNAME&key=YOUR_KEY

Edited:

For v2:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/frangarcia?v=2&alt=json and you will the channelId at json.entry.yt$channelId.$t

Comment: I need v2 version because i don't have my all accounts are token

Comment: Your example nice but my problem is "i don't have my user or channel id" My question is get channel id. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

To get a YouTube channels [User ID] or [Channel ID], you simply need to navigate to the channels home page and look at the navigation bar of your browser and look for either:

1. "**/channel/**" or "**/user/**"
2. The text that follows and ends with the next "/" copy that text **without** the "/" and you have your Channels or Users ID.

Thanks for the Channel ID code and in case you don’t have the User ID code.

**User ID Code:** [http://www.youtube.com/rss/user/[User_ID]/feed.rss](http://www.youtube.com/rss/user/%5bUser_ID%5d/feed.rss) which will translate in your browser to the relevant code, that is required to work. Unfortunately I can't seem to find any such code that work the same for channels with only Channel ID displaying and not the User ID which would have been great.

Check out **Derral Eves** "How to Find the RSS Feed for Your Youtube Channel": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DevXRvPa3dU, for a visual demonstration on how to find the youtube channels RSS Feed for a [User ID] and is where I found my information.

Terry